# Perdendo Foco do EditText ao clicar duas vezes no recyclerview

Tags: android

Estou com um recyclerview com dois EditText tudo funciona muito bem, o problema é quando eu clico duas vezes fora do EditText ele perde o foco e aparece o teclado alfanumérico sendo que o EditText é apenas numérico. Na verdade isso não vai trazer muitos problemas para meu aplicativo não mais gostaria de saber o motivo desse comportamento. Se alguém souber o movivo.

Answer (score 0):

Gente quem estiver tendo problemas com foco no `recyclerview` o problema pode está na notificação do adaptador.

Toda vez que você notifica o adaptador ele perde o foco. No meu caso eu estava com `EditText`, quando eu clicava pela segunda vez em um item do `recyclerview`, eu fazia uma notificação com `notifyDataSetChanged();` e meu `EditText` perdia o foco. Se alguém tiver uma maneira de EditText não perder o foco por favor poderia postar.

Comment: Você ainda não conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Resolvi de outra forma, mas não como eu queria, Gostaria de dá requestfocus, mas não funcionou. o que funcionou para mim foi cancelar o teclado quando faço a notificação com notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Na verdade eu nem queria que ele perdesse o foco.